# I can not import magento_sample_data_for_1.6.1.0.sql in my Magento database

Tags: magento

I am really astonished about magento.I am trying to import **magento_sample_data_for_1.6.1.0.sql** in my **magento-1.8.0.0_2** database.
When I trying to import it gives error like ***Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.0.4\libraries\dbi\mysqli.dbi.lib.php on line 267***  I have changed **max_execution_time = 300** to **max_execution_time = 0** first time and second time  **max_execution_time = 300** to **max_execution_time = 3600** in php.ini file.You can see the image Which I posted!Can anybody help me to find what is wrong with me.Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same problem with import so here is a solution that worked for me.
Go to wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.0.4/libraries and open config.default file. 
Find $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 300 and change value to 0 (0 means no limit) and restart wamp. Then try import again.

Answer (score 2):

After changing **max_execution_time** restart Apache although better solution would be importing database using command line

> mysql -u[username] -p [database_name] < {path_to_your_sample_data}/your_sample_data.sql

Answer (score 1):

restart the computer after changing the execution time for taking affets